# Input type file not working while using on modalmanager of react Js

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I am working with react js , And On a modal box i am having a input type file , but when i click on it, it is not opening window for file browsing. 
if i put same syntax somewhere else other then that modal box it is working good.

We are using rubix  ref : http://rubix305.sketchpixy.com/app/dashboard

```
 export default class extends React.Component {
      getModal() {
        return (
            <MyModal Id={this.props.id}/>
       );
     }

    render()
    {
      return(
          <a href="#" onClick={ModalManager.create.bind(this, this.getModal())} onTouchEnd={ModalManager.create.bind(this, this.getModal())}>Click to open</a>
       );
    }
 }

 class MyModal extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

     render() {
       <Form>
         <FormGroup>
           <Grid>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <input type='file' />   
                </Col>
             </Row>
           <Grid>
        </FormGroup>
     </Form>
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code to give a bit of context ?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?